# Saving exe file using fs.writeFile

Tags: node.js, electron

I am trying to save the exe file from https location and save it for local use. File is saved but I get this error when try to run it "Error: Command failed: C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\testapp\Updates\update.exe
'C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\testapp\Updates\update.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." When I run the update.exe from file explorer I get this error "This app can't run on your PC. To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher"

```
const updaterUrl = 'https://xxx.xxx.com/updates/';

function downloadUpdate(filename) {
  // filename is update.exe
  https.get(updaterUrl + filename, (resp) => {
    let data = '';

    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });

    resp.on('end', () => {
      let dir = path.join(app.getPath('userData'), 'Updates')
      let p = path.join(app.getPath('userData'), 'Updates', filename)

      if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(dir, 484);
      }

      fs.writeFile(p, data, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error: ' + err.message)
        } else {
          runUpdate(p);
        }
      })
    });

  }).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Update error: " + err.message);
  });
}

function runUpdate(path) {
  exec(path, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
  });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is not complete (for example `filename` and `runUpdate` are not defined). Please use the edit link underneath your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: I am sorry. I have updated the description.

Comment: So, the error message doesn't include the correct filename?

Comment: It does. Problem is that the file is not executable after save. It has exe file, but cannot be executed even from file explorer.

Comment: Please include all relevant information such as these (including full error messages) in the question. In particular, please include the explorer error message. Please update the original error message to indicate that there is indeed a file path given.

Comment: Updated description